# Linux: copy one file from several directories

Tags: linux, copy, tar

I have a situation where I want to copy a specific file "transaction.log" from thousands of directories under linux and build a tar file containing those same specific files.

Example:
I have thousands of directories under /user/foo/dirs/

```
/user/foo/dirs/dir1
/user/foo/dirs/dir2
/user/foo/dirs/dir3
..
..
..
/user/foo/dirs/dir50000
```

In each directories, there are several files and a transaction.log file. I would like to copy this transaction.log file from all the 50000 directories and store them in a tar file.

Can you please help me if there is a way to do so?

Thanks.

## SOLUTION:

Okies, i found the issue, since there were some sympolic links to other disks find was not working well. solution is to use with -follow option with find to follow the symbolic links. thanks. 
I use the following command

find . -follow -type f -name "transaction.log" | tar --create --files-from - > /foo/Stats_transaction_Object.tar.gz

Comment: What you got going on so far?

Comment: You can use wildcards.
$ tar -cvf tarname.tar /user/foo/dirs/dir*/transaction.log

Answer (score 2):

The one with {} isn't bad, but it'll run a separate tar process for each file.  This is a single tar process, so it's quite a bit faster:

```
find /where/ever -name transaction.log -print | tar --create --files-from - > /somewhere/else/foo.tar
```

Comment: -print is the default and it is probably more efficient to have tar create the archive rather than have it be done from the shell redirection...

Comment: Thank you dstromberg. I tried your advice but the tar file got created has only 7747 directories containing 'transaction.log' file. and I have about 50K directories which contain this file. I noticed with teppic suggestion it was 7743 files. Is there some limitation on linux for doing do?

Comment: -print is the default on some find's, especially GNU find.  On other find's there is no default action.

Comment: I would try find /where/ever -name transaction.log -print | wc -l

Answer (score 1):

You can use this commands:

```
cd /user/foo/dirs/
find . -type f -name "transaction.log" | xargs tar -zcvf transaction_logs_backup.tar.gz
```

Comment: If the length of the listing of transaction.log files exceeds xargs limit for one command invocation (usually 4K) you will have an incomplete archive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to store the directory path as well:

```
find /user/foo/dirs/ -name 'transaction.log' -exec tar rf /tmp/stuff.tar {} \;
```

This will store every transaction.log file found within that directory structure in /tmp/stuff.tar.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your advice but the tar file got created has only 7743 directories containing 'transaction.log' file. and I have about 50K directories which contain this file. Is there some limitation on linux for doing do?

Comment: Okies, i found the issue, since there were some sympolic links to other disks find was not working well. solution is to use with -follow option with find to follow the symbolic links. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

find /user/foo/dirs -name transaction.log | tar -cv -T- -f /tmp/stuff.tar